# SQL Grouping and Counting based on dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, count, grouping

Getting nowhere here and seems so simple.

Test data is:

```
declare @table table(SpellAdminsionDate datetime, SpellDischargeDate datetime, Pat_code varchar(10))
 insert into @table (SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values('2016-09-12 15:55:00:000','2016-09-19 20:20:00:000','HEY3052275')
 insert into @table(SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values ('2016-09-07 17:17:00:000','2016-09-17 18:40:00:000','HEY0810155')
 insert into @table(SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values ('2016-09-14 16:50:00:000','2016-09-17 18:01:00:000','HEY1059266')
 insert into @table(SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values ('2016-09-15 02:47:00:000','2016-09-15 17:28:00:000','HEY0742883')
 insert into @table(SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values ('2016-08-27 00:11:00:000','2016-09-14 12:49:00:000','HEY3050628')
 insert into @table(SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values ('2016-09-10 12:24:00:000','2016-09-13 20:00:00:000','HEY0912392')
 insert into @table(SpellAdminsionDate, SpellDischargeDate, Pat_code) values ('2016-09-12 12:51:00:000','2016-09-13 19:55:00:000','HEY0908691')

 Select * from @table`
```

Below is my simple code displaying the same thing:

```
SELECT c.SpellAdmissionDate, 
       c.SpellDischargeDate,
       c.Pat_Code
FROM [CommDB].[dbo].[vwCivicaSLAM1617Live] c
WHERE c.Hrg_Code like 'VA%'
    and c.Pat_Code like 'HEY%'
ORDER BY c.SpellDischargeDate desc
```

All I am after is a `COUNT` per day of active patients, for example take the `12/09/2016` on that date the result would be `5` (based on the test data) as the other 2 cam in after the 12th.

If it makes it easier I do have a date reference table called `DATE_REFERENCE` which has every date available to me.

Comment: Add some of that `DATE_REFERENCE` table to your question and you'll get your answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing for the possibility of having no patients on a day then you want to use your date reference table as the primary and left join to the patient information. You don't identify a column name so I just used [datecol].

```
SELECT
      d.[datecol]                 the_date
    , count(DISTINCT c.Pat_Code) num_patients
FROM DATE_REFERENCE d
LEFT JOIN [CommDB].[dbo].[vwCivicaSLAM1617Live] c
            ON d.[datecol] BETWEEN c.SpellAdmissionDate AND c.SpellDischargeDate
            AND c.Hrg_Code LIKE 'VA%'
            AND c.Pat_Code LIKE 'HEY%'
GROUP BY 
      d.[datecol]
ORDER BY
      d.[datecol] DESC
```

I suspect there may be more than this required, but without sample data and expected results it is difficult to know what you really need.

nb. I assume the date in that date_reference table is at midnight (00:00:00) or has a data type of date (without hours/minutes etc.)

Comment: This looks close I'm validating now to be 100%

Comment: Ding Dang Do, this is exactly the simple solution I was looking for and knew was out here somewhere, thank you kindly

Comment: Great. I presume you will then tick this as the solution so that others know the question has been answered.

Comment: will you ever return to this? perhaps you would care to consider "ticking" the solution? it costs you nothing - but we get a tiny recognition for our effort and assistance

Comment: Apologies I've never used this before and was looking for something the 'SOLVED PROBLEM' didn't thing it was the obvious tick.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT dr.date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [CommDB].[dbo].[vwCivicaSLAM1617Live] c
        WHERE dr.date between c.SpellAdmissionDate and c.SpellDischargeDate) as cnt_per_day
FROM DATE_REFERENCE dr
```

Add the filters you want to the correlated query .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by joining to your date reference table and counting by a distinct of the patient reference

```
SELECT
 dateRef
,COUNT(DISTINCT Pat_Code) AS PatCount
FROM @table t
RIGHT JOIN @date_reference
ON SpellAdminsionDate <= dateRef
AND SpellDischargeDate >= dateRef
GROUP BY dateRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

Active count of patients per date can be achieved by (for temp data provided here)

```
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST(T1.SPELLADMINSIONDATE AS DATE)
  AdmissionDate,PATIENTS.TotalActive
  FROM @TABLE T1 
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*)TotalActive FROM @TABLE T2 WHERE
  CAST(T2.SPELLADMINSIONDATE AS DATE)<=CAST(T1.SPELLADMINSIONDATE AS DATE))    PATIENTS
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to bring the DATE_REFERENCE table to the Query If it contains all the day dates that you need to count patients based on them, But here is a sample of how may you get the required result form this table only

```
  Select DISTINCT c.SpellAdmissionDate, count(c.Pat_code) as PCounter 
  From [CommDB].[dbo].[vwCivicaSLAM1617Live] c
  GROUP BY c.SpellAdmissionDate
  ORDER BY c.SpellAdmissionDate desc
```

Comment: never use `select distinct` and `group by` this way... the group by must by definition produce distinctive rows making`select distinct` fully redundant